# ValueError while converting list to string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a udp listener function on 2 hosts. It is supposed to behave like this: Whenever host1 receives a udp message starting with "10.0.0", it will convert a list to string and will send it through udp socket. If any other message is reached to host1, it will convert the message from string to a list. Here is the code:

```
def read_udp(s):
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    if data.startswith('10.0.0'):
        data_split = data.split(" ")
        num = int(data_split[1])
        ipToTransfer = address
        transferStart = start[-num:]   
        msg = pickle.dumps(transferStart)
        udp_send(msg, ipToTransfer)
    else:
        recvStart = pickle.loads(data)

def udp_send(s, ip):
    UDP_IP = ip
    if(type(s) == str):
        MESSAGE = s
    else:
        MESSAGE = pickle.dumps(s)   
    print ("UDP target IP & port:", UDP_IP, port)
    #print ("message:", MESSAGE)
    sock3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock3.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, port))
```

This code was working fine when the length of the list was under 60 ~ 65, but when the list length grows above this value, I face an error saying that:

```
File "process.py", line 273, in <module>
   run
File "process.py", line 127, in read_udp
   recvStart = pickle.loads(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
   return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
   dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 960, in load_float
   self.append(float(self.readline()[:-1]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

This is line 127 of my code: `recvStart = pickle.loads(data)`

What's wrong? I can't figure out the problem since it was working when the length of my list was under 60.

I tested 2 scenarios. In the first one 8 elements were in the list and the output of pickle.dumps for each of them was like this:

> Element in the list: 1549286402.7232   pickle.dump output:
>   aF1549286402.7232

but now when I test it with 60 elements in the list, the output for each element of the list is like before, but there is a `a.` at the end of the string representation of the list. What is this and is it the reason of my problem?

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float` obvious. Post your line 960

Comment: @user5173426 line 960 does not exist in my code, it seems to be an error inside pickle.py

Comment: @BenyaminJafari yeah, it's this line: `recvStart = pickle.loads(data)`, but I can't figure out what's wrong with that.

Comment: What does `data` look like when the error is thrown? Perhaps `print(data)` before the `recvStart` line.